# Change the name of class in cellstr

Tags: matlab

For example,type of class are apple, orange, and grape.
Now im using apple as the class in my matlab code,how to I change the class from apple to orange in cellstr without change the word 'apple' to 'orange' one by one?

```
class=[cellstr('apple');cellstr('apple');cellstr('apple');cellstr('apple')];
```

which means that i just type one of the class like orange and it will create a new class as shown below.

```
 class=[cellstr('orange');cellstr('orange');cellstr('orange');cellstr('orange')];
```

Answer (score 0):

`class` is name of a function, don't use it as a name of variables.

```
>> c = repmat({'apple'}, 4, 1)

c = 

    'apple'
    'apple'
    'apple'
    'apple'

>> b = strrep(c, 'apple', 'orange')

b = 

    'orange'
    'orange'
    'orange'
    'orange'
```